# Will openings near the corner of a slab compromise its strength?

Tags: concrete, slab

I'm planning to build a 10x8 shed that will house the pipework and electrical equipment for a new well I recently had drilled. I would like the shed to sit on a concrete slab just for the quality of life it provides.  My well contractor suggested that I pour the slab first, leaving 1x1 holes roughly 1' in from the corners where I can run pipework through afterwards.

- Once the slab is finished with the holes, does it compromise the integrity of slab if I were to dig out the dirt between the hole and the edge of the slab to run the pipes?
- How best to fill/pack dirt  back in after the pipes are put in place?  Should I fill the holes with concrete, or just pack in gravel to be flush with the surface of the slab?

Rough drawing of what it'll be like:
[image]

Comment: Run rope through the pipes befire burying and concreting.

Answer (score 2):

You could use large Schedule 40 PVC as conduit for the pipes. You'd use large radius bends. Will the pipes be PEX or copper? I think soft copper could be fed through a large radius bend and I am sure PEX could be. This would make replacing piping much easier if you ever needed to replace the piping under the slab.

Comment: The pipe is going to be poly pipe, so it should be very easy to work with.  There will also be an electrical conduit going to the wellhead.  I suppose that doesn't need to be in the slab; it can run down the side of the building.

Comment: Could you be more specific in your term "poly" pipe?

Comment: How large conduit are you thinking?  2" or bigger?

Comment: 250PSI rated polyethylene 1-1/4" CTS pipe

Comment: I am not familiar with the bending properties of 1-1/4" CTS pipe. I suppose normally it goes more or less straight from a water main to a meter in a box or can in the ground and is direct burial. Using PVC as a conduit might not be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, openings that large and so near the edges will compromise the slab's strength. It will be difficult to support the adjacent corners after excavation in a reliable way and they are much more likely to crack loose. I would install extra rebar or mesh through those areas to make the slab edge essentially self-supporting.

How you fill the openings later is totally up to you. I'd use washed rock if available, otherwise gravel.